# Cannot verify method calls with mockito in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mockito

I am trying to use Mockito to do some verifications about the number of times a method was called, but the syntax that I'm seeing in all the tutorials I can find is causing an "Unresolved compilation problem" error in eclipse. The class I'm mocking is:

```
public class ClassToBeMocked {
    public void methodToVerify(String input) {

    }
}
```

The test is:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTest {
    @Mock ClassToBeMocked mockedClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.mockedClass = Mockito.mock(ClassToBeMocked.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Mockito.verify(mockedClass, Mockito.never()).methodToVerify();
    }
}
```

But when I try to run the test in eclipse, I get this error:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method methodToVerify(String) in the type ClassToBeMocked is not applicable for the arguments ()

at MockitoTest.test(MockitoTest.java:28)
at . . .
```

At first blush, the error seems logical: after all, it appears as though I am calling a method without passing in the required parameters. But I thought Mockito would do some under-the-hood work to make it work.

If my use of the framework is wrong, then how *should* I be verifying this method?

I'm using Mockito version 2.7.6. I have not tried running the test outside of eclipse because I'm new to java/junit/mockito/maven, and I haven't yet figured out how to run the tests from the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to include an argument matcher, e.g. [`anyString()`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.6/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyString()):

```
Mockito.verify(mockedClass, Mockito.never()).methodToVerify(Mockito.anyString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Mockito.verify(mockedClass, Mockito.never()).methodToVerify(anyString());
```

Use above sentence